# Rotate view when device rotated with locked orientation

Tags: android, rotation, screen-rotation

In my app i need to rotate a few views when device rotated.

I'm using

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

It's important not to re-create activity on rotation but just rotate few views.
When I'm trying

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    Log.i("info","changed");
```

nothing happened

So, the **main question** is: how to handle **device** rotation when screen interface still the same.

Update #1

I need to work with the same activity when device rotated because of Camera object and other stuff!
Like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/INHUF.jpg (have no 10 reputatiuon to post image)

Comment: Writing `android:configChanges="orientation"` means that the activity you have declared that wont be recreated on configuration change. To lock the orientation you can do `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. From your question it is not clear what you are exactly trying to achieve. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: But if I ll use different layouts I ll see animation of rotating whole screen. I ll try using fragments, but I'm not really understand what keys do I need to use? configChanges="orientation" or android:screenOrientation="portrait" and what ll handle rotation?

Comment: If you want to keep your view as it is even when the screen is rotated use `configChanges="orientation" `.
If you want to force your app stay in one mode (ex: portrait mode) use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

If you are using two layouts(protrait different than landscape) than you name them with the same name but you put them in different folders(`layout` and `layout-land`). When in landscape mode, android will get the layout from `layout-land` and if in `portrait mode`, it will take it from `layout`

Comment: I know that, but when user rotate device i want to show animation of rotating views. config change and orientation will be used but how could I handle event that device was rotated physically and in what side?

Comment: If you want to animate then you have to fig up a little about android animation. For physicall rotation check [Accelerometer](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125)

Comment: Looks like accelerometer is what I m looking for